# Resample from regular to irregular time series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a regular time series of data and I need to average it to a predefined irregular time series. I figured there would be something simple in df.groupby or df.resample but couldn't find it. My basic code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

reg_data = pd.Series(
    np.arange(25),
    index=pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-02', freq='H')
    )
new_start_times = [
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,2,5,12),
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,6,0,0),
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,12,7,58)
    ]
new_end_times = [
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,3,7,28),
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,7,0,0),
    dt.datetime(2018,1,1,19,55,22)
    ]
```

So I want the reg_data, averaged between the new start and end times

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with selecting by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) with `mean`:

```
L = [reg_data.loc[s:e].mean() for s, e in zip(new_start_times, new_end_times)]  
print (L)
[3.0, 6.5, 16.0]
```

EDIT: You can round values by [`Timestamp.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html):

```
L = [reg_data.loc[s.round('H'):e.round('H')].mean() 
     for s, e in zip(pd.to_datetime(new_start_times), pd.to_datetime(new_end_times))]  
print (L)
[2.5, 6.5, 16.0]
```

Or:

```
L = [reg_data.loc[s:e].mean() 
     for s, e in zip(pd.to_datetime(new_start_times).round('H'), 
                     pd.to_datetime(new_end_times).round('H'))]  
print (L)
[2.5, 6.5, 16.0]
```

Comment: Thanks this works pretty well! However it only includes values that lie between the start and end times. Is there a way to give it a tolerance for the nearest value? For example, the last time interval is 12:07 - 19:55, so that would be better as 12:00 - 20:00 rather than 13:00 - 19:00

Comment: Cool so I could also round the time in the original data (if needed) and that would give me flexibility on what sort of time delta to accept. Thanks!

Comment: @AstonVillarrealMadrid - Yop, good idea. Added to answer.